# How to make tesseract to recognize only numbers, when they are mixed with letters?

Tags: ocr, tesseract

I want to use `tesseract` to recognize only numbers. The problem is that I have mixture of numbers & letters and when I use `SetVariable("tessedit_char_whitelist", "0123456789")`
for every symbol tesseract returns wrong digit.

Can I set a threshold value so that `tesseract` omits the symbols with low resemblance?

NOTE: I set `tesseract` to recognize only digits so there is no confusion between O and 0.

Comment: Hi there, I am also using Tesseract with Java project and I am facing some issues, I have business cards images and I need to extract email addresses, the problem is that sometimes it makes confusion between numbers and letters, the email "j.schneiderheinze@dunskie.de" becomes "j.5chneiderheinze@dunskie.de", would you have and idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 43):

Recognizing only numbers is actually answered on the [tesseract FAQ](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/FAQ-Old#how-do-i-recognize-only-digits) page.  See that page for more info, but if you have the version 3 package, the config files are already set up.  You just specify on the commandline:

```
tesseract image.tif outputbase nobatch digits
```

As for the threshold value, I'm not sure which you mean.  If your input is an unusual font, perhaps you might retrain with a sample of your input.  An alternative is to change tesseract's pruning threshold.  Both options are also mentioned in the FAQ.

Answer (score 16):

For tesseract 3, the command is simpler `tesseract imagename outputbase digits` according to the [FAQ](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/FAQ-Old#how-do-i-recognize-only-digits). But it doesn't work for me very well.

I turn to try different `psm` options and find `-psm 6` works best for my case.

`man tesseract` for details.

Comment: The said digit-related info has been removed from the FAQ.

Answer (score 15):

If one want to match 0-9

```
tesseract myimage.png stdout -c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789
```

Or if one almost wants to match 0-9, but with one or more different characters

```
tesseract myimage.png stdout -c tessedit_char_whitelist=01234ABCDE
```

Answer (score 14):

For tesseract 3, i try to create config file according [FAQ](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/FAQ-Old#how-do-i-recognize-only-digits).

BEFORE calling an Init function or put this in a text file called `tessdata/configs/digits`:

```
tessedit_char_whitelist 0123456789
```

then, it works by using the command: `tesseract  imagename  outputbase  digits`

Answer (score 10):

I made it a bit different (with tess-two). Maybe it will be useful for somebody.

So you need to initialize first the API.

```
TessBaseAPI baseApi = new TessBaseAPI();
baseApi.init(datapath, language, ocrEngineMode);
```

Then set the following variables

```
baseApi.setPageSegMode(TessBaseAPI.PageSegMode.PSM_SINGLE_LINE);
baseApi.setVariable(TessBaseAPI.VAR_CHAR_BLACKLIST, "!?@#$%&*()<>_-+=/:;'\"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz");
baseApi.setVariable(TessBaseAPI.VAR_CHAR_WHITELIST, ".,0123456789");
baseApi.setVariable("classify_bln_numeric_mode", "1");
```

In this way the engine will check only the numbers.

Answer (score 6):

add "--psm 7 -c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789'" works for me when the image contain's only 1 line.

Answer (score 4):

This feature is not supported in version 4. You can still use it via -c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789 with "--oem 0" which reverts to the old model.

[There is a bounty to fix this issue.](https://www.bountysource.com/issues/42806964-blacklist-and-whitelist-unsupported-with-lstm-4-0)

**Possible workarounds:**

As stated by [@amitdo](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/issues/751#issuecomment-423521780)

- Using the --oem 0 option (the legacy engine will be used)
- Retraining (fine tuning)
  [#751 (comment)](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/issues/751#issuecomment-333904808)
- Post-processing
  [#751 (comment)](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/issues/751#issuecomment-375408508)

Answer (score 4):

```
custom_oem=r'digits --oem 1 --psm 7 -c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789'

text = tess.image_to_string(croped,config=custom_oem)
```

I am using tesseract 4.1.1.

For better result you might want to consider Image processing techniques.

Answer (score 3):

You can instruct tesseract to use only digits, and if that is not accurate enough then best chance of getting better results is to go trough training process:
http://www.resolveradiologic.com/blog/2013/01/15/training-tesseract/

Comment: I don't know why this answer is second when it's the least helpful and wrong. There is no **need** to go through training process again just to blacklist characters!

Comment: Blacklisting characters wasn't mentioned in my answer, but in some cases even if I had instructed tesseract to use numbers they weren't being recognized as such. In such cases training is only way forward. If you have gotten better results with some other process please share your experience.

Answer (score -2):

What I do is to recognize everything, and when I have the text, I take out all the characters except numbers

```
//This replaces all except numbers from 0 to 9
recognizedText = recognizedText.replaceAll("[^0-9]+", " ");
```

This works pretty well for me.

Comment: You're missing the chance to improve quality and speed of OCR. If you restrict Tesseract to given set of characters, it will perform better. With your approach you're loosing valuable information.